# Bullets not showing with cv4tw

Tags: cv

I am using the package cv4tw to create a CV and I am currently trying to compile the providing example with an updated version of Mikex 2.9 and TexniCenter 2.02.

The Tex file is [here](http://osl.ugr.es/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/cv4tw/examples/sample-jules-verne-sharp.tex)

My main problem is that the small icons next to the mail, phone fields are not displayed. See the pdf of the example [here](http://osl.ugr.es/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/cv4tw/examples/sample-jules-verne-sharp.pdf)

Thanks for the help

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I get the symbols, except for `\faCircleBlank` that's apparently undefined in `fontawesome`; it became `\faCircleO`, so adding `\newcommand{\faCircleBlank}{\faCircleO}` to the preamble solves this issue.

Comment: After a clean Miktex reinstall and the use of your command, it is now working properly! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The `fontawesome` package underwent several changes in the last few months, so it's possible you need an update of your TeX distribution.

However, the class uses a command that's no more defined. Add

```
\newcommand{\faCircleBlank}{\faCircleO}
```

to the document preamble in order to solve this issue, so the old command points to the new one.